# Does 'Conservation of momentum' obey Newton's 2nd law of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

Conservation of momentum is valid when $F_{\rm external}=0$ and $F_{\rm internal}$ not equal to zero. According to Newton's 2nd law of motion $F=dp/dt$, so if there is a force acting there will be a change in momenta and vice-versa. If there is a force (internal) acting there should be a change in momenta, but in conservation of momentum $P(i)=P(f)$, there is no change in momentum, initial momentum=final momentum. Is this a violation of Newton's 2nd law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Newton's second law of motion is applicable for any point object or even for system of two or more objects (and for system , you need to define  the center of mass to apply Newton's laws).

Consider two small spherical objects (say $m_1$ and $m_2$ ) in free space and suppose they can interact with each other only Gravitationally.

---

**Case 1** : Take the two masses as separate bodies (i.e. don't take both as a system)

The force experienced by $m_1$ due to $m_2$ or $m_2$ due to $m_1$  will not be considered as internal forces and thus we can easily say that since external force is acting on the two bodies, their momentum should change. No doubt with this case.

---

**Case 2** : Take both the masses as a system .

Since there is no external source to apply force on that **system** , we can deduce from Newton's second law that the momentum of the system is conserved.

**But how ?**

Since you took both the masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ as a system , you need to define the **center of mass** of that system since Newton's laws are applicable only to **a point object**.

Of course due to mutual interaction , their individual momentum will change but since both are experiencing the same amount of force ($F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$) for the same time (say $t_1$) their **combined change in momentum (i.e. momentum of center of mass)** is zero .

**How ?**

We know that

$\delta P_{cm} = (m_1)(\delta v_1) + (m_2)(\delta v_2)$
And the addition  is a **vector addition**.

$\delta P_{cm} = F_{m_1} t_1 + F_{m_2}t_1 $

And from Newton's third law :

$F_{m_1} = - F_{m_2}$

and so **the  change in momentum of center of mass is zero.**

---

Newton's second law of motion:

$F_{ext}$ = $\frac{\delta P_{cm}}{dt}$

---

So , when you take a system of two or more bodies , then because of internal forces between each pairs , the individual momentum will change but the combined momentum (i.e. momentum of center of mass) doesn't change and this is exactly what Newton's second law predicts . So their is no **VIOLATION**.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: @Angeline varghese I have tried to solve your doubt. Please comment either if it was helpful or if their is some doubt .

Comment: But in case 2 :we consider as system, so inside a system the total internal forces are zero because they cancel out eachother, which means there is no external and internal forces, which means no force which explains no change in momentum(F=dp/dt), that means momentum is constant. Am I right? If it is correct can we conclude that the conservation of momentum is valid when there is no force acting on the body ? I mean when Fnet=0

Comment: @Angeline varghese  when you are taking them as a system , the net internal forces are zero and yes that's why the net momentum of the**system** doesn't change i.e it is constant. Yes when $F_{net\;external}$ = 0  then no change in momentum because internal forces always cancel each other out inside a system.

Comment: Can we conclude that the conservation of momentum is valid when there is no force acting on the body ? I mean when Fnet=0

Comment: @Angeline varghese yes you can say that . It is for sure true but again remember that the momentum of individual bodies in the system is not conserved because they do experience some net force.

Answer (score 4):

A more comprehensive way to think of conservation of momentum (for objects or for systems) is this:
$$\vec{p}_f=\vec{p}_i + \int \vec{F}_{net} \mathrm{d}t$$
where the $\vec{p}$ items are the final and initial momentum, respectively, of the object or the system, however you wish to look at it. $\vec{F}_{net}$ is the net force applied to the object or the system. This is true conservation because it says that momentum is neither created nor destroyed; it is transferred into or out of objects and systems.

[Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) describes the relationship between symmetries and conservation laws, along with currents. Force is the agent which transfers momentum, rather than creating or destroying it.
If $\vec{F}_{net}$ is zero, the momentum remains *constant* for that object or system. If $\vec{F}_{net}$ is not zero, the momentum changes, but it is still conserved because we know the momentum went or came from somewhere outside our defined system.

If the momentum of a single object changes, we know that an outside net force acted on it, transferring the momentum in or out. The momentum of the object may not be constant, but the momentum is conserved. Newton's 2nd Law says
$$\vec{F}_{net}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{p}}{\mathrm{d}t},$$ which is exactly the converse of the equation above.

Momentum has an analogous behavior to charge: total charge in a system may change (e.g., current flow through a capacitor), but that's because charges flow in and out. Same thing happens with momentum.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you define as your system. If there are no external forces on that system then the momentum of that system is conserved according to Newton's second law. As an example, two objects colliding in outer space with no external forces acting on them. The total momentum of the two objects is conserved. If we define our "system" to be just one of the objects, then there will be an external force on it (due to the other object) and its momentum will change according to Newton's second law.

Comment: Are you tring to say that newton's 2nd law of motion is only for an obeject. It is not for a system?

Comment: It can be used for a system. If there were an external force acting on the two objects, and they were our system, then we would use Newton's 2nd law to find the resulting motion of the center of mass of the system. Or we would use the force on each object to determine its individual motion. @d_b points out below that the law itself is for a single particle but by derivation it can be applied to a system of particles.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 2nd law only applies to a single particle. However, we can use Newton's laws to derive an analogous result for the motion of a system of particles under the influence of a net external force. Consider a system of $N$ particles. Applying Newton's 2nd law to the $i$-th particle,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F}_{\text{net},i} = \frac{d \mathbf{p}_i}{dt}
\end{align}
Adding these equations, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{F}_{\text{net},i} &= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{d \mathbf{p}_i}{dt}\\
&= \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{p}_i
\end{align}
On the right-hand side,
Divide the forces on each particle into internal and external forces. Internal forces only act between particles in the system, while external forces are exerted by particles outside the system.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F}_{\text{net},i} = \mathbf{F}^{\text{int}}_{\text{net},i} + \mathbf{F}^{\text{ext}}_{\text{net},i}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{F}_{\text{net},i} = \sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{F}^{\text{int}}_{\text{net},i} + \sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{F}^{\text{ext}}_{\text{net},i}
\end{align}
By Newton's 3rd law, the sum of the net internal forces is zero, since
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{F}^{\text{int}}_{\text{net},i} = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j\neq i}^N \mathbf{F}_{i \text{ on } j}
\end{align}
and for any two particles in the system, $\mathbf{F}_{i \text{ on } j} = -\mathbf{F}_{j \text{ on } i}$. We end up with
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F}^{\text{ext}}_{\text{net}} = \frac{d\mathbf{p}_{\text{tot}}}{dt} ,
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{p}_{\text{tot}} = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{p}_i$ is the total momentum of the system and $\mathbf{F}^{\text{ext}}_{\text{net}} = \sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{F}^{\text{ext}}_{\text{net},i}$ is the net external force on the system.

So we have a dynamical equation for a system of particles analogous to Newton's 2nd law $\mathbf{F}_\text{net} = d\mathbf{p}/dt$, with the net force replaced by the net external force, and the momentum replaced by the total momentum of the system.

Comment: So is it right to say that "the change in total momentum in a system of particles is equal to the total momentum of that system" ?

Comment: No, and I hope I didn't write anything that gave you that impression. Instead I would say "the change in total momentum of a system of particles is equal to the net external force on that system."

Answer (score 0):

The crux here is "definition of a system".

It's completely our choice that what we define our system.Internal forces in the system can change the momentum of constituent particles of the system but they can't change the net momentum of the system.

The only factor which can change the net momentum of the system is a net external force on the system.

More precisely:

$$\vec{P_{system,final}}=\vec{P_{system,initial}} +\int\vec{F_{ext}} dt$$

Now it's clear that what determines the net final momentum of a system is the impulse of net external force.